# How do I use a function to pass parameter to the function received as props in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
export default class InputBlock extends Component{
handleChange = (e, props) =>{                //Checked passing props didn't worked.
    const inputVal = this.msgInput.value;
    props.onMessageSent(inputVal);
    e.preventDefault();
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                <input type="text" className="msgInput" ref = {input => this.msgInput = input}/>
                <input type="submit" value = "submit" className="sendButton" />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Here I am receiving function onMessageSent function as a props from parent component. I want to pass the value of input to the function so that I can set that value to state and pass it as a prop to different component. Here 's my parent Component:-

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import Messages from './Messages';
import InputBlock from './InputBlock';

export default class MainInterface extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sent: [],
            received: []
        }
    }   

    onMessageSent = (val) =>{
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          sent: [...prevState.sent, val]
        }))
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Messages sent={this.state.sent} received={this.state.received}/>
                <InputBlock onChange = {this.onMessageSent} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**There was a type it should be onMessageSent instead of onMessagesent. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your components are defined as ES6 classes, in this case you can refer component's props as `this.props` without need to pass them as argument to your class methods. So your method should look like:

```
handleChange(e) {
    const inputVal = this.msgInput.value;
    this.props.onChange(inputVal);
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onMessageSent is not a function

Comment: You're right, I've missed that you're passing your function as `onChange` property. I've updated answer

Comment: thats all just some typo problem

Comment: I must delete this post now

Answer (score 0):

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
export default class InputBlock extends Component{
handleChange = (e) =>{                //Checked passing props didn't worked.
    const inputVal = this.msgInput.value;
    this.props.onMessageSent(inputVal);
    e.preventDefault();
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                <input type="text" className="msgInput" ref = {input => this.msgInput = input}/>
                <input type="submit" value = "submit" className="sendButton" />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

import React, {Component} from 'react';

import Messages from './Messages';
import InputBlock from './InputBlock';

export default class MainInterface extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sent: [],
            received: []
        }
        this.onMessageSent= this.onMessageSent.bind(this)
    }   

    onMessagesent = (val) =>{
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          sent: [...prevState.sent, val]
        }))
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Messages sent={this.state.sent} received={this.state.received}/>
                <InputBlock onChange = {this.onMessageSent)} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```